# Uploading java website made in struts2 using war file

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts2, hosting

I have made a website in java and struts2 ,now I want to host it live but I am unable to host it. I tried by uploading WAR file and extracting it in cpanel but still not working. I have account on hostbudget.com and I have bought their server.

Can anyone help me how can I upload my Java project since its my first time, I took suggestions from many friends of mine but none of them has clear idea of this.

Comment: Do you have Apache Tomcat on your host? How is it not working?

Comment: not web site its webapplication. Since till now you are not  hosted in any remote server

Comment: yes its apache server only but i dont know the procedure which i followed for hosting whether it was right or not 
:(

Comment: You must have WHM cpanel account to host your application. Later deploay war in cpanel. Before that you must instal servlets in WHM cpanel.

Comment: no @Satya sir its my first time . i know some of the concepts like it should be uploaded in public_html folder only

Comment: where i can find that whm cpanel ?

Comment: No you must have WHM cpanel. Other wise java will not be supported. PHP is defautly supported by cpanel. Not java.

Comment: okay so where i can find that whm cpanel ?

Comment: Ask your server vendors. They will provide it. I think we have some dedicated server.

Comment: i have not bought dedicated ip ? so is that the issue ? so can i now change my plan by having talk with vendors ?

Comment: Ask them They will guide you better.

Comment: okay thankyou sir :) i will let you know later on what i did finally :)

Answer (score 1):

cpanel doesn't support java by default. It only supports PHP by default.

See this link. [How to deploy java web application (WAR) through my GoDaddy's cPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017467/how-to-deploy-java-web-application-war-through-my-godaddys-cpanel)

WHM cpanel https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+Tomcat

**Steps to deploy java web application in cpanel:**

1. Select your public_html directory.
2. Click Upload.
3. Click Choose File
4. Browse your WAR file.
5. Change the file extension from .war to .zip
6. Select the .zip file and click Extract.

Before that you must install servlets in WHM cpanel. If you need any help to install then the server vendors will guide you.

Some of them told me that enter the following text in **.htaccess** file inside your **public_html** directory

```
  SetHandler jakarta-servlet
  SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

It's not needed. Since without this my app working.